# Cocos2d UITableView Edit Button Showing but not Showing Delete Icon

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, cocos2d-iphone

Ok, so my project (which does have Cocos2d) has 3 UITableViews. So far, I am only concerned with the first one, which is why I am only pasting the code for the first one. The problem is, whenever I use the app, the table view shows up, with all of it's content. The edit/done button also shows up as it is supposed to in the right hand corner. However, whenever I try to hit the edit button, the button switches to Done, but there is no delete icon near the cells, nor can I delete the cells. I have tried many solutions, but none of them seem to work. Thanks in advance.

```
-(id)init{
if (self == [super init]) {
    // Create initialized instance of UITabBarController
    tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    // Create initialized instance of NSMutableArray to hold our UINavigationControllers
    tabArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Create first UIViewController
    questionController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self makeQuestionTable];
    [questionController setTitle:@"Question"];
    // Initialize the UINavigationController
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:questionController];
    questionController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = questionController.editButtonItem;
    questionTableView.allowsSelection = YES;
    questionTableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
    questionTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
    // Add UINavigationController to you tabs
    [tabArray addObject:navigationController];
    // Release UIViewController and UINavigationController
    [questionController release], [navigationController release];

    // Create second UIViewController
    answerController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self makeAnswerTable];
    [answerController setTitle:@"Answer"];
    // Initialize the UINavigationController
   navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:answerController];
    // Add UINavigationController to you tabs
    [tabArray addObject:navigationController];
    // Release UIViewController and UINavigationController
    [answerController release], [navigationController release];


    // Create third UIViewController
    colorController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self makeColorTable];
    [colorController setTitle:@"Color"];
    // Initialize the UINavigationController
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:colorController];
    // Add UINavigationController to you tabs
    [tabArray addObject:navigationController];
    // Release UIViewController and UINavigationController
    [colorController release], [navigationController release];

    // Add the tabs to the UITabBarController
    [tabController setViewControllers:tabArray];
    // Add the view of the UITabBarController to the window
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view]addSubview:tabController.view];
}
return self;
}
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{

[questionTableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
[questionController setEditing:editing animated:animated];

}
-(void)makeQuestionTable{
questionTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)          style:UITableViewStylePlain];
questionTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
questionTableView.delegate = self;
questionTableView.dataSource = self;
questionTableView.tag = 1;
[questionTableView reloadData];
[questionController.view addSubview:questionTableView];
}

-(void)makeAnswerTable{
answerTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)     style:UITableViewStylePlain];
answerTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
answerTableView.delegate = self;
answerTableView.dataSource = self;
answerTableView.tag = 2;
[answerTableView reloadData];
[answerController.view addSubview:answerTableView];

}

-(void)makeColorTable{

colorTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
colorTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
colorTableView.delegate = self;
colorTableView.dataSource = self;
colorTableView.tag = 3;
[colorTableView reloadData];
[colorController.view addSubview:colorTableView];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if (currentTab == 1) {
    return [appDelegate.questionArray count];
}
else if (currentTab == 2) {
    return [appDelegate.answerArray count];
}
else if (currentTab == 3) {
    return [appDelegate.colorArray count];
}
else{
    return 0;
}
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
if (tableView.tag == 1) {


static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [appDelegate.questionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
    NSLog(@"Question");
}
if(tableView.tag == 2){

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [appDelegate.answerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
    NSLog(@"Answer");
}
if(tableView.tag == 3){

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [appDelegate.colorArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
    NSLog(@"Color");
}
}
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView
       editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [questionTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if ([cell isEditing]) {
    NSLog(@"YES");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"NO");
}
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
// This only needs to be implemented if you are going to be returning NO
// for some items. By default, all items are editable.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath     {
// Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:    (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    //add code here for when you hit delete
    [questionTableView delete:indexPath];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `edit` button action, you need to give `setEditing` as `YES`.

```
[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: WOW! Thanks! It FINALLY responds! The ONLY problem is, whenever I click it, it blinks as if it has been clicked, with the delete icon, and then blinks again, and the delete icon disappears as if I never clicked it?

Comment: If you can answer this, I'll give you the bounty @arthan.v ;)

Comment: can you tell me when that delete icon is disappearing?

Comment: Ok, so I figured out why it is blinking. It is because, I have a self schedule that is repeatedly reloading the data in the table, which is resetting the cells as not clicked. However, if I delete this line, then the tableview doesn't load up at all. I tried reloading it somewhere else, but it doesn't reload? Thanks @arthan.v

Comment: Ok, so NOW, I got everything(almost) to work. The delete stays there, but when I hit delete, nothing happens? The cell doesn't go away, it just stops :P. Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: In ur `viewController`, u need to implement `commitEditingStyle` delegate method. In that method, check and delete the row. `if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexpaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];}. i don't remember, i think u can give `animationStyle`, instead of `YES
`

Answer (score 0):

Set the tableView's property 'editing' to be 'YES'. Like:

```
questionTableView.editing = YES;
```

Delete this line:

```
questionTableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```

or  set `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing` to be 'NO' when you select.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a couple closing curly braces right before `- (void)setEditing` and shouldn't your init method `return self;`

Comment: 1: No I'm not? 2: No, this is Objective-C. You just have return, not return:

Comment: Yes, you are. Are you even looking at the code you posted? Your -(id)init method is NOT closed.

Comment: Ah sorry, I was looking at only the setEditing part. I fixed it :)